# Add extracted line to 3Dplot in RasterVis

Tags: raster, r

Trying to use the following (from another post) without success.

```
plot3D(r, col = rainbow, adjust=FALSE)

lines3d(xyz)
```

Raster, r, is from https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-density-rev11.  The extent is reduced.  No problem using plot3D for this with adjust=TRUE.  However, adjust=FALSE appears to plot a vertical line.

[image]

Then, data.frame, xyz is lon, lat, population density created using extract along the point set (xy) of a (road) route taken from a KML.  Above then appears to plot r, but it is drastically reduced in the graphic space and it isn't clear that the path has been added to it.

My goal is to simply add a (road) route line on top of the population density terrain.